# How to add <Text> before FlatList where data is fetch through database

Tags: react-native

I am getting data from database that has client details and then list of client's properties and information of each property. I can get FlatList to display the list of the properties but what I want to display is the client details first, etc and then FlatList displaying property details. How can I extract client details from the array and display it first and then properties' details.

eg of array is something like this

[{'id': "90", 'clientname': "Client Name", 'balance': "10000",{'propid': "80", propname: 'Property Name', 'rented': "Rented", 'rent': '10000'},{'propid': "70", propname: 'Property Name 2', 'rented': "Not Rented", 'rent': '4000'}}]

```
<Text>{clientname}</Text><Text>Your Balance {balance}</Text>

<FlatList>......<FlatList>
```

As I mentioned I can get Property FlatList displayed correctly. What I cannot get is to display the client specific details.

UPDATE:

Thank you to those who tried to help but it did not work for me. I am putting the code here may be someone can check to see what can be done. I have removed stylesheets and other data that is not relevant.

```
    ["client_name": "Client Name", "balance:" 40599.00", "contract_expiring": "4,
{"id":"94","area":"Central","building":"Building 108","unit":"104B", "rent_amount": "40000", 
{"id":"22","area":"North East","building":"Building 555","unit":"1304", "rent_amount": "15000"}]

export default class ClientDetails extends Component {


        constructor() {
            super()
            this.state = {
               isLoading: true
            }
        }
        renderItem = ({ item }) => {
            return (
         <View>
         <Text>
    {item.building}
    </Text>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: '#2a5566', marginBottom: 10 }}>
           {item.unit}
           </Text>

           <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, color: 'green' }}>
            Rent Amount:  {item.rent_amount}
            </Text>
        </View>

            )
          }



        componentDidMount = () => {
        return fetch("http://192.168.0.106/db_1/list.php?itemId=194")
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((responseJson) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoading: false,
                        dataSource: responseJson,

                    })
                })

        }






        render() {
    return (
           <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
      <FlatList
                data={ this.state.dataSource }
                   ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.renderSeparator}
         renderItem={this.renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    />
     </View>

            );
        }
    }
```

This Part (**["client_name": "Client Name", "balance:" 40599.00", "contract_expiring": "4,**) of array I don't want to be part of FlatList but separately displayed above the FlatList.

Thanks.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58581614/6544460 is it you want?

Answer (score 1):

`react-native Flatlist` offers a `ListHeaderComponent` prop that you can use for this. As docs:

> Rendered at the top of all the items. Can be a React Component Class, a render function, or a rendered element.

So in your `Flatlist` list you can just use it as :

```
<Flatlist
   ...
   ListHeaderComponent={<Text>Hello</Text>}
/>
```

Source: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#listheadercomponent

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [
  {'id': "90", 'clientname': "Client Name", 'balance': "10000"},
  {'propid': "80", propname: 'Property Name', 'rented': "Rented", 'rent': '10000'}
]
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <View> 
      <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>Client Name - {data[0].clientname}</Text> 
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <View>
              <Text>{item.clientname}</Text>
              <Text>{item.propname}</Text>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```